# Riot Analysis Program

Tags: python, api, tkinter

This is a riot analysis app. Collect data using the riot API and shows the user various data. Nothing too in depth.

**GUI file** - This file is the GUI file for the program. I have the class that make the rest of the frames of the program. After clicking the button to search for a summoner, it will collect data from another class in game and return a list of 5 data's with each being a different type(kill, death, assists, vision, wins). I have two global variable that I don't want to use in DataCollected class, I can't seem to find a way not to use them.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont
from getId import id_collected
from games import Game
from wins import is_player_good


class RiotApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, MenuPage, KillPage, DeathPage, CsPage, HonestPage):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        c = DataCollected()
        self.controller = controller
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter summoner name:", width = 20, font = ("bold", 20))
        self.label.place(x=90,y=53)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.place(x=190,y=130)
        
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Search",width = 20, bg = 'brown', fg = 'white',
                            command=lambda: data_collected(self,controller))
        self.button.place(x=180,y=200)

        def data_collected(self,controller):
        
            name = self.entry.get()
            Key = '****************************************'
            a = id_collected(name, Key)
            if a != 'NO':
                controller.show_frame("MenuPage")
                c.collect_data(name, Key)
            else:
                controller.show_frame('StartPage')

class DataCollected():
    
    def collect_data(self, name, Key):

        num_games = 20
        game = Game()
        accId = id_collected(name, Key)
        game_list = game.find_game_ids(accId, Key, num_games)
        global stat_list
        stat_list = game.game_data(game_list, Key, name, num_games)
        global honest
        honest = is_player_good(stat_list[5])

class MenuPage(tk.Frame,DataCollected):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Main Menu", font=controller.title_font)
        label.place(x=180,y=50)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Kill Average",width = 20, bg = 'brown', fg = 'white',
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("KillPage")).place(x=180,y=100)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Death Average",width = 20, bg = 'brown', fg = 'white',
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("DeathPage")).place(x=180,y=150)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Cs Average",width = 20, bg = 'brown', fg = 'white',
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("CsPage")).place(x=180,y=200)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Honest Truth",width = 20, bg = 'brown', fg = 'white',
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("HonestPage")).place(x=180,y=250)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Back",width = 20, bg = 'brown', fg = 'white',
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage")).place(x=180,y=300)

class KillPage(tk.Frame, DataCollected):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text = 'Kills Average', width=20,font=("bold", 20))
        self.label.place(x=90, y=100)
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text = ' ', width=20,font=("bold", 20))
        self.label1.place(x=90, y=150)
        self.label1.after(1000, self.refresh_label)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text = "Back", width = 20, bg = 'brown', fg = 'white',
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("MenuPage")).place(x=180,y=300)

    def refresh_label(self):
        self.label1.configure(text = stat_list[1])
        self.label1.after(1000,self.refresh_label)

class DeathPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text = 'Deaths Average', width=20,font=("bold", 20))
        self.label.place(x=90, y=100)
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, text="", width=20,font=("bold", 20))
        self.label2.place(x=90, y=150)
        self.label2.after(1000, self.refresh_label)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Back", width = 20, bg = 'brown', fg = 'white',
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("MenuPage")).place(x=180,y=300)

    def refresh_label(self):
        self.label2.configure(text = stat_list[0])
        self.label2.after(1000,self.refresh_label)

class CsPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text = 'Cs Average', width=20,font=("bold", 20))
        self.label.place(x=90, y=100)
        self.label3 = tk.Label(self, text="", width=20,font=("bold", 20))
        self.label3.place(x=90,y=150)
        self.label3.after(1000, self.refresh_label)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Back", width = 20, bg = 'brown', fg = 'white',
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("MenuPage")).place(x=180,y=300)

    def refresh_label(self):
        self.label3.configure(text = stat_list[4])
        self.label3.after(1000,self.refresh_label)

class HonestPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text = 'Honest Truth', width=20,font=("bold", 20))
        self.label.place(x=90, y=100)
        self.label4 = tk.Label(self, text = " ", width=20,font=("bold", 20))
        self.label4.place(x=90,y=150)
        self.label4.after(1000, self.refresh_label())
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text = "Back", width = 20, bg = 'brown', fg = 'white',
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("MenuPage")).place(x=180,y=300)

    def refresh_label(self):
        self.label4.configure(text = honest)
        self.label4.after(1000,self.refresh_label)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    stat_list = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    honest = ' '
    root = RiotApp()
    root.geometry("500x500")
    root.mainloop()
```

**Game file** - This file start by collecting game ids and using the game ids to collect the stats of said summoner in each of there 20 games. Then returns it to gui file.

```
import requests

class Game:

    def find_game_ids(self, accId, key, num_games):
        i = 0
        GAMEID = []
        num_games = 20
        url_match_list = ('https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v4/matchlists/by-account/' + (accId) + '?queue=420&endIndex=20&api_key=' + (key))
        response2 = requests.get(url_match_list)
        # Adding 20 games into the list
        while num_games > 0:
            GAMEID.append('https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v4/matches/'+str(response2.json()['matches'][i]['gameId']) + '?api_key=' + (key))
            i = i + 1
            num_games = num_games - 1

        return GAMEID

    def game_data(self, game_list, key, sumName, num_games):

        wins = []
        deaths = []
        deaths = []
        kills = []
        assists = []
        visions = []
        csTotal = []
        # Finding the data of said summoner in each game id
        for urls in game_list:
            response = requests.get(urls)
            resp_json = response.json()
            Loop = 0
            index = 0
            while Loop <= 10:

                if resp_json['participantIdentities'][index]['player']['summonerName'] != sumName:
                    Loop = Loop+1
                    index = index+1
                elif resp_json['participantIdentities'][index]['player']['summonerName'] == sumName:

                    deaths.append(resp_json['participants'][index]['stats']['deaths'])
                    kills.append(resp_json['participants'][index]['stats']['kills'])
                    assists.append(resp_json['participants'][index]['stats']['assists'])
                    visions.append(resp_json['participants'][index]['stats']['visionScore'])
                    csTotal.append(resp_json['participants'][index]['stats']['totalMinionsKilled'])
                    wins.append(resp_json['participants'][index]['stats']['win'])

                    break
        # Finding avg of each stat
        deaths = sum(deaths)/num_games
        kills = sum(kills)/num_games
        assists = sum(assists)/num_games
        visions = sum(visions)/num_games
        csTotal = sum(csTotal)/num_games
        wins = sum(wins)/num_games
        stat_list = []
        stat_list.append(deaths) #0
        stat_list.append(kills) #1
        stat_list.append(assists) #2
        stat_list.append(visions) #3
        stat_list.append(csTotal) #4
        stat_list.append(wins) #5

        return stat_list
```

**Get id file** - This file collect the summoner id for the Game class in game file.

```
import requests

def id_collected(sumName, key):
    # COLLECTING DATA TO BE INSERTING FOR MATCHLIST DATABASE
    url = ('https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/'+(sumName)+'?api_key='+ 
(key))
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        accId = (response.json()['accountId'])
        return accId
    else: 
        accId = 'NO'
        return accId
```

**wins file** - This file will use the `stat_list[5]` to determine whether the player has been good in past 20 games and will return a phrase.

```
import random


def is_player_good(winlist):

    if winlist < 0.33:
        message = ['DIS MANE STINKS', 'run while you can', 'I repeat, YOU ARE NOT WINNING THIS', 'I predict a fat L', 'Have fun trying to carry this person', 'He is a walking trash can', 'He needs to find a new game', 'BAD LUCK!!!']
        return (random.choice(message))

    elif winlist > 0.33 and winlist <= 0.5:
        message = ['Losing a bit', 'Not very good', 'He needs lots of help', 'Your back might hurt a little', 'Does not win much']
        return (random.choice(message))

    elif winlist > 0.5 and winlist <= 0.65:
        message = ['He is ight', 'He can win a lil', 'You guys have a decent chance to win', 'Serviceable', 'Should be a dub']
        return (random.choice(message))

    elif winlist > 0.65:
        message = ['DUB!', 'You getting carried', 'His back gonna hurt a bit', 'winner winner chicken dinner', 'Dude wins TOO MUCH', 'You aint even gotta try', 'GODLIKE']
        return (random.choice(message))
```

Comment: Please fix your title so that it states what your code does, also [edit] your question and explain the purpose of your code properly

Comment: Where are those globals mentioned in the topic?

Comment: they are in DataCollected class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Local variables

Since `F` is a local variable - even though it's technically a reference to a class, and classes are capitalized - `F` should be lower-case. Also, it deserves to have a name that isn't one letter. `Key` should also be lower-case.

### Lambdas

This:

```
command=lambda: data_collected(self,controller))
```

does not deserve to be a lambda. Since you're also storing `controller` on `self`, it's better to simply make a method on the class for this, and pass a bound reference to that method for `command`.

### Position-sensitive lists

```
stat_list[5]
```

is a code smell. My guess is that this is a list of statistics, where each position in the list is a different kind of statistic. This should be converted to a class, or at the least, a named tuple.

### In-place addition

```
i = i + 1
```

should be

```
i += 1
```

### Range testing

```
winlist > 0.33 and winlist <= 0.5
```

should be

```
0.33 < winlist <= 0.5
```

### Parens

This:

```
return (random.choice(message))
```

does not need outer parens and should remove them.

### Typo?

In `He is ight`.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. You have any suggestions for the global variables in DataCollected class? I heard using global variables are not good. The problem is that frames are already made so I can't seem to collect the data and put it into the labels for the frames.

Comment: If I have this right, `HonestPage.refresh_label` relies on being able to read `honest`, which you've made a global in `DataCollected.collect_data`. This seems like the former is the UI and the latter is the logic or data layer.  The place where these fail to be connected is `StartPage.__init__`, where `DataCollected` is initialized but then no references are made to it. This needs to change or move so that there are references between the data collector and the user interface.